# "Systems those were" or "systems that were"?

Tags: grammar, agreement, appositives

Please, someone, help me to understand why is this first sentence incorrect?

1. Incorrect: And it has affected the most to the *systems those* were already fragile.
2. Correct: And it has affected the most to the *systems that* were already fragile.
3. Correct: And it has affected the most to the *system those* were already fragile.

Since *"systems"* is plural shouldn't it be okay to use *"those"* with it?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't say that any of those sentences are grammatical. *Affected the most to the system* is incorrectly phrased, and it doesn't matter if you follow it by *that* or *those*.

Comment: A phrase like *effective system **those** were* is grammatical, although unusual. It changes the normal subject-verb-object order to object-subject-verb. That's the order famously used by Yoda in the *Star Wars* movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: the "that" in the correct sentence is a relative pronoun. Sometimes it can be left out; sometimes "which" can be used instead. But "that" is used for both singular and plural. It does not have a separate plural form. So "those" is never correct in that circumstance.

"That" in that sense is not to be confused with the adjective "that" as in "that system".

Comment: Thanks, Rosie, that makes sense. Can you please shed some light on the 3rd sentence? I believe this one is grammatical, but using "those".